# What are some steps I can take to improve the feel of my dash?

Tags: unity, movement

I'm trying to implement a dash ability for my player that feels good, but what I have right now sort of feels "flat." What I have is pretty simple, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    [SerializeField]
    private float dashLength = 5;
    [SerializeField]
    private float dashDuration = 0.2f;

    private IEnumerator DashCoroutine() 
    {
        // I am deriving this from one of the kinematic equations (0 acceleration)
        float dashForce = dashLength / dashDuration;
        float elapsedTime = 0;

        while (elapsedTime < dashDuration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(transform.right * dashForce * Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen others suggest adding something like a slight camera shake, but my question is more about strategies for manipulating the horizontal velocity so that it doesn't just feel like my player is rigidly speeding up and then returning to normal movement. However, I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you want to achieve with a gif?

Comment: Can we assume you've [studied up](https://youtu.be/216_5nu4aVQ) on [juice](https://youtu.be/Fy0aCDmgnxg) and [game feel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3385050-game-feel)? What kinds of animation, VFX, sound, or haptic feedback are you using at the moment?